# URL Rewrite fror dynamic URL with single parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Want the URL to be:

```
http://localhost/web/a-st/type/car
```

Base URL is `http://localhost/web/a-st/`

**Rewrite Rule that i tried:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^type/([^/]*)$ /type.php?name=$1 [L]
```

**ERROR Showing:**

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: You are using an absolute path as a target. I assume you mean a relative path, since `type.php` most likely is lcoated inside the `web` folder? So remove the `/` before the `type.php`

Comment: Checked not Working. @arkascha

Comment: And what does "not working" mean? Which URL _is_ called internally? Check the server logs, there is little sense in _guessing_ it IT.

Comment: Oh, you _do_ have rewriting enabled, don't you?

Comment: And the best as always: _Turn on rewrite logging_. It explains in detail what is going on inside the rewriting engine. Clearly shows up the point where unexpected or undesired things start to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means start, so it would match `example.com/type/ca` use RewriteBase or define the extra `web/a-st` within the rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/a-st
RewriteRule ^type/([^/]*)$ /type.php?name=$1 [L]
```